# How do I post comments using the YouTube API on Android?

Tags: android, youtube-api

How do I post comments using the YouTube API on Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to let the app user authenticate, just as though you're coming from a web application like this:

[Authentication API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_authsub.html)

Then when you have the AUTH token, the app can collect the user's comment, wrap it up in the [appropriate call](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_comments.html) and submit it.